# I want to use Vue Fallthrough attributes, however I do not want them to be placed on the container, only on input inside component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a checkbox component and I want to use Fallthrough attributes to provide non declared attributes to the input inside the checkbox component. However, when I place html attributes on the Vue component, the attributes are not only placed on the input in the container, but also on the container element of the checkbox component.

This is my component html

```
    <template>
      <div class="form-checkbox">
        <v-label
          v-if="legend"
          :suffix="legendSuffix"
          :for="$attrs.id || uid"
          :helper="helperText"
        >
          {{ legend }}
        </v-label>
    
        <div class="form-input__wrapper">
          <input
            :id="$attrs.id || uid"
            ref="checkboxRef"
            type="checkbox"
            v-bind="$attrs"
            v-model="inputVal"
            @input="onInput"
          />
    
          <label :for="$attrs.id || uid">{{ label }}</label>
        </div>
    
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts" src="./Checkbox.ts" />
```

This is my component ts

```
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    legend: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    legendSuffix: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    helperText: { type: String, default: '' },
    label: { type: String, default: '' },
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: ''
    }
  },

  emits: ['error', 'input-event', 'mounted'],

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const checkboxRef = ref();
    const inputVal = ref();
    const uid = ref(uniqueId());

    watch(
      () => props.modelValue,
      () => {
        inputVal.value = String(props.modelValue);
      },
      { immediate: true }
    );

    const onInput = (event: CustomEvent): void => {
      emit('input-event', event);
    };

    onMounted(() => emit('mounted', unref(checkboxRef)));

    return {
      checkboxRef,
      inputVal,
      uid,
      onInput
    };
  }
});
```

Currently when I load the component like this, the ID property is placed on the container  AND on the checkbox input.

```
    <v-checkbox
      id="test"
      :label="test"
    />
```

Is there a way to prevent the attributes from being placed on the container AND the input? Because now the ID is used twice and that breaks everything.

Comment: RTM https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance

Comment: Thanks haha I read that a few times, but I misread is as it disabling Fallthrough attributes fully, I should read it better next time, thanks

Comment: You may answer question youself for the case someone ask it again, or close it instead, you you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to disable attribute inheritance, see documentation

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance

> ### Disabling Attribute Inheritance {#disabling-attribute-inheritance}
>
> If you do **not** want a component to automatically inherit attributes, you can set `inheritAttrs: false` in the component's options.
>
> Since 3.3 you can also use [`defineOptions`](/api/sfc-script-setup#defineoptions) directly in `<script setup>`:
>
> ```js
> <script setup>
> defineOptions({
>   inheritAttrs: false
> })
> // ...setup logic
> </script>
> ```
>
> The common scenario for disabling attribute inheritance is when attributes need to be applied to other elements besides the root node. By setting the > `inheritAttrs` option to `false`, you can take full control over where the fallthrough attributes should be applied.
>
> These fallthrough attributes can be accessed directly in template expressions as `$attrs`:
>
> ```
> <span>Fallthrough attributes: {{ $attrs }}</span>
> ```

The `$attrs` object includes all attributes that are not declared by the component's `props` or `emits` options (e.g., `class`, `style`, `v-on` listeners, etc.).